# How do I copy all rows with a specific value in one of their columns to another spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Microsoft Office 2013 RT

I have a spreadsheet showing the results of survey. I need to copy all of the respondents who answered "Yes" to specific questions to their own spreadsheet, and then sort those respondents by what school they go to (selected from a drop down menu in the original survey). I'll need to do this multiple times for a variety of questions, because they will need to be visualized soon (e.g. 20% of students in the Art Department admitted to taking Adderall without a prescription).

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have all the information in one sheet?

Answer (score 0):

A classic case for a PivotTable, it would appear. Assuming data as in A1:G10, a PT (in I1, constructed as indicated) and double-clicking J8 should return (in a different sheet, but shown here in A13:G16, for the sake of the image):

[image: SO21900460 example]

The filtering options may be changed and double-clicking create further sheets with the relevant extracts.